# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal calling php function in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

What I am trying to do here is call my php function from inside of a javascript function and it throws the  unterminated string literal error from

```
var letters = "<?php echo GetRandLine('en_lang.txt'); ?>";
```

allthough the php function is returned correctly. What the php function is doing is returning a list of words to search from en_lang.txt.So from what I have gatherd it is processing the the `<?php  ?>` as the `</script>` tag or is it something else.

php:

```
    if (!function_exists('GetRandLine'))
    {
        function GetRandLine($name)
        {
            $file = fopen("$name","r");
        $text = array();
        $count = 0;

        while(!feof($file))
        {
            ++$count;
            $text[] = fgets($file);
            //echo fgets($file). "<br />";
        }

        fclose($file);

        $n = rand(0,100);

        $ntext = $text[rand(0,$count)];
        //echo $n." ";
        if($n > 50)
        {
            $ntext = $ntext . " " . $text[rand(0,$count)];
        }
        if($n > 80 && $n < 90)
        {
            $ntext = $ntext . " " . $text[rand(0,$count)];
        }
        if($n > 85 && $n < 88)
        {
            $ntext = $ntext . " " . $text[rand(0,$count)];
        }

        return $ntext;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
    function clicker() 
    {
        var letters = "<?php echo GetRandLine('en_lang.txt'); ?>";
        document.getElementById('theinput').value = letters;
        document.getElementById("clicker").click();

    }
```

Comment: try to escape double quotes.  `addslashes(GetRandLine('en_lang.txt'))`

Comment: Please note that it's impossible to, as you say, call a PHP function from inside a JavaScript function. By the time the JavaScript gets its turn, the PHP has long been executed and the contents of the string are simply the result of the function. To JavaScript it looks like it's hard-coded.

Comment: @Mr Lister Thanks I am not used to mixing up different languages. i am used to C++ and calling functions from inside other functions when ever needed. I am still trying to figure out the does and dont's of web design and how everything works together. So in this case I guess I can quit being lazy and just right a javascript function I am having trouble reading and writing files using javascript so I thought i could just create a php function and call it like that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string returned from GetRandLine may have troublesome characters in it, including newline which causes the error you mentioned, you should encode it

```
var letters = <?php echo json_encode(GetRandLine('en_lang.txt')); ?>;
```

Comment: Before I started trying this method I tried new File(txtFile);  and kept getting a NS_ERROR_FAILURE code. What is wrong with FILE I know the directory was correct ect?